# Azure Data factory pipeline - dynamically get tenant ID

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

So, I need to dynamically get tenant id inside the data factory pipeline.  Can anyone help in how to construct dynamic expression ?
So, for instance, am running a POST request to get SharePoint authentication token and for that I have the URL:

```
https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/<TenantID>/tokens/OAuth/2
```

So, the part

```
https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/
```

will be stored as a global parameter.
And my goal is to construct a dynamic expression inside the activity that would look like this

```
@concat(pipeline().globalParameters.MSFTAccessControl_BaseURL,**<getTenantId>**, '/tokens/OAuth/2')
```

I need help with the function to construct the part ****<getTenantId>****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below Powershell script to get the Tenant ID.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$tenant=Get-AzureADTenantDetail
$tenant.ObjectId
```

[image]

Execute this **Powershell script from ADF using custom activity**.

You can go through this [tutorial](https://azurelib.com/custom-activity-powershell-script-azure-data-factory/) by **@**Deepak Goyal**** to know about how to execute a Powershell script using custom activity.

After this custom activity, **get the above Tenant Id** from its output using the below dynamic content.
`@activity('<MyCustomActivity>').output.customOutput`

Store it in a variable and use it in building your Sharepoint link using concat or String interpolation like this.

```
@concat(pipeline().globalParameters.MSFTAccessControl_BaseURL,variables('tenant id'), '/tokens/OAuth/2')
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was really hoping to avoid calling custom activity, but seems this is the way.  Thank you for confirming.

Comment: @DmitriyRyabin - if you can control the deployment of ADF, you might manually define this as a globalParameter and then include an  override param for the ARM deployment. 

then in your pipeline, you just need to reference: @pipeline().globalParameters.tenantId


This isn't as ideal as just pulling it from the environment. (let me know if you find a direct way)
We do this for our KV Uri, when need to manually access secrets directly.